# How to tackle 'Error in order: argument 1 is not a vector' error in R

Tags: json, r, shiny

I am building a shiny app in R. In the server script, I have the following code to clean the data from a `GET` request:

```
  output$tubeArrival <-  renderTable({

#GET request and convert JSON to a dataframe
data <-  GET(url)
text_data <-  content(data,as = 'text')
json_data <-  fromJSON(text_data)

#return an error
json_data <- json_data[order(json_data$timeToStation),]
})
```

And then the line of `order()` throws an error:

```
Warning: Error in order: argument 1 is not a vector
Stack trace (innermost first):
83: order
82: renderTable [#47]
81: func
80: origRenderFunc
79: output$tubeArrival
 4: <Anonymous>
 3: do.call
 2: print.shiny.appobj
 1: <Promise>
```

The `order()` function works well outside the server environment.

Note: This is what the json data looks like:

[image: [Json]

Comment: The problem isn't obvious to me, because your screenshot shows `timeToStation` is an 'int' vector.  Run `class(timeToStation)` right before the call to order.  What does it say?

Comment: To get better responses, consider stripping out the lines that are unnecessary to the problem, such as the creation o f `timeToArrive` and everything after the error.

Comment: @wibeasley: it returns 'integer' for class(timeToStation)

Comment: I'm stumped -it's a vector immediately (according to `class(timeToStation)` right before `order()` says it's not).  Nothing changed in between?  Maybe try `json_data <- dplyr::arrange(json_data, timeToStation)`.

Comment: This particular problem isn't related to shiny.  When you call it from a normal R script (where `url` is hard-coded), does anything change?  Also, replace `order()` with `base::order()`, to see if there's a naming collision.

Comment: @wibeasley: it works perfectly in the normal r script. When used the dplyr arrange(), it throws back a error: 'Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'arrange_' applied to an object of class "list"'.

Comment: @wibeasley: and base : : order() has the same error as before

Comment: It sounds like there is some naming collision with some Shiny mechanism.  I don't know if a reactive is making that int vector a list.  I guess create a small Shiny app with nothing but that function (and a hard-coded `url`).  Slowly add features/functions to the app until you find the troublemaker.

Comment: @wibeasley: The error actually eliminated when I replaced the url variable with a hard-coded url

Comment: Huh, I can't explain the connection, but I'm glad it's figured out.